# power series tayllor arrest criteria problem

Tags: c++, taylor-series

Hi guys i created a c program to confront taylor taylor series of cosine and interpolation but i have a problem . The problem is about the function cosine (calculated by using taylor method) because the programme  always gives me a  degree of 3 , or 1 . My teacher said that i should use this arrest criteria

`x^(2k)/(2k!)<t` where t is tau in my code , the tolerance. Really thanks to anyone who can help me!

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>



double read_tolerance();
double put_x();
void cosine(double,double,int &,double,double);
double Li(int,int,double[],double);
double Pn(int,double[],double[],double);
void interpo_Lagrange(int);


int main()
{
    
    int k=1;
    double cos_initial=1,a=1;
   
    double tau=read_tolerance();
    double x=put_x();   
    cosine (cos_initial,a,k,x,tau);
    interpo_Lagrange(k+1);
return 0;
}
    
double read_tolerance() 
{
    double t;
    
        printf("\n choose the value of tolerance: ");
        scanf("%lf", &t);
    
    return t;
}

double put_x()
{
    double x;
    
    printf("\nput value of  x: ");
    scanf("%lf",&x);
    
    return x;
}

void cosine(double coseno,double a,int &k,double x,double tau)
{
     do {
    a *= pow(-1,k)*((x*x) / (2*k));
    coseno += a;
    k=k+2;
    
}while (a> tau);

printf("value of cosine of %lf is %lf\n",x,coseno);
printf("degree with taylor is ' %d\n",k);
return ;
}

double Li(int i, int n, double x[], double X){
    int j;
    double prod=1;
    for(j=0;j<=n;j++){
        if(j!=i)
            prod=prod*(X-x[j])/(x[i]-x[j]);
    }
        return prod;
}

double Pn(int n, double x[], double y[], double X){
    double sum=0;
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<=n;i++){
        sum=sum+Li(i,n,x,X)*y[i];
    }
    return sum;
}


void interpo_Lagrange(int n)
{
     int i;  
    printf("the number of data-points are %d:\n",n);
      
    
    
    double x[n];
    double y[n];
    printf("Enter the x data-points:\n");
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++){
        x[i]=Pi*i/(8);
        printf("%lf\n",x[i]);
    }
     
    printf("Enter the y data-points:\n");
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++){
    
    y[i]=cos(Pi*i/(8));
        printf("%lf\n",y[i]);
    }
     
    double X;  
    printf("Enter the value of x for which you want the interpolated value of y(x):\n");
    scanf("%lf",&X);
    printf("The interpolated value is %lf",Pn(n,x,y,X));
}
```

Comment: Try this: `while (std::abs(a)> tau);` `a` can be negative !!

Comment: Besides, I don't think the formula is correct. The power of `x` should increase with iterations

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: Although the code looks largely like C code, it uses `int &` as a parameter type, showing it is C++, and should be tagged C++, not C.

Comment: @AlfredoCozzolini: Please do not tag questions with both C and C++ (except for questions that involve interactions or differences between the languages). Use only the tag for the language you are programming in.

Comment: @Eric Postpischil you are right sorry :(

Comment: @Damien now iterations with your help  are ok  but i still don't know how to change my arrest criteria  and make it correct.

Comment: @AlfredoCozzolini I provided the stopping criteria in my first comment. Doesn't it work?

Comment: @Damien yes now with your correction the code works , but you said after that the formula is not correct, so i don't know what should i change

Answer (score 0):

The implementation of tayllor series is incorrect and here is the right one

```
do {
    a *= -((x * x) / ((2 * k - 1) * (2 * k)));
    coseno += a;
    k = k + 1;
} while (fabs(a) > tau);
```

i hope this fixes your problem

Answer (score 0):

The first issue is that the term can be negative. So the stopping criteria
must used the absolute value of it.

Another issue is that the used formula is not correct. The calculation of the denominator (fatorial) was not correct.

A last issue is that is is better a little bit that the function return the calculated value: more clear.

Output:

```
cos calculated = 0.707107
Error = -1.14623e-010
```

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

double cosine (double x, double tolerance) {
    double x2 = x*x;
    double term = 1;
    double y = 1;
    int sign = -1;
    int k = 2;
    do {
        term *= x2/(k*(k-1));
        y += sign * term;
        k += 2;
        sign = -sign;
    } while (term > tolerance);
    
    return y;
}

int main() {
    double tolerance = 1.0e-6;
    double angle = 3.141592/4;
    double calculated = cosine (angle, tolerance);
    double exact = cos(angle);
    double err = calculated - exact;
    std::cout << "cos calculated = " << calculated << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Error = " << err << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, the code I proposed was correct. However, the explanation why your code was not working was incorrect. Answer corrected.

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer and the explanation you are great :).